# Aspose Words file upload and default font

Tags: java, spring, file-upload, aspose, aspose.words

I'm currently working on a reporting application, where users input data and the application generates metrics and compiles a report on said data. The Word templates have been created with a Calibri font

However, when users edit the report offline (i.e. in MS Word) and subsequently re-upload the report, the updated report is all in Times New Roman.

Has anyone else run into a similar issue with Aspose and would there be any suggestions on how to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade to the latest version of [Aspose.Words for Java](http://www.aspose.com/downloads/words-family/java) and see how it goes on your end. Hope, this helps.

In case the problem still remains, please report this issue in [Aspose.Words forum](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.words-product-family/75/showforum.aspx). Please zip and attach your 1) input Word document, 2) output document and 3) code example.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.